# ASPX : Databind on a gridview taking 30 minutes it only for Pagesize = True

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an issue with the DataBind on a gridview for which i set the `AllowPaging` to `False`.
I have about 60 rows on my table in the DB, when i link that to my Gridview it's taking 30 minutes on the command `MyGridView.DataBind();`
It doesn't take time when i set the `AllowPaging` to `True` and when the `PageSize` is set to `2`.
But even for `PageSize` set to `5`, it's taking forever.

```
myList = MyDBEntities.PopulateMyTable().ToList();
MyGridView.DataSource = myList;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

```html
 ALTER PROCEDURE  SP_GetTable
 SELECT * FROM MyTable 

 public List<MyTable> PopulateMyTable()
        {
            using (dbEntities db = new dbEntities())
            {
                return db.SP_GetTable().ToList();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Something is very, very wrong. Can you show your implementation of `PopulateMyTable`?

Comment: 30 Mins to read 60 records..!! There is a high possibility that you have something wrong in your DB itself. It is impossible guess anything with the code that you have posted? Where is the code for PopulateMyTable? where are you doing the paging at DB level? or after all the records are fetched to server?

Comment: I added the code of the method and of the stored procedure

Comment: Hello, Anyone ? please help !!!!